# Moving raw pointer contents to vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a raw pointer, say,

```
char * ptr = (char *) malloc(LIMIT);  
size_t size;  
fill_with_data(ptr, LIMIT, &size);
```

Now I'd like to wrap the pointer data using `std::vector`.

```
auto v = vector<char>(ptr, ptr + size);
```

But I think using the syntax above will produce a copy of the pointer's contents. Is there any way to convert a raw pointer to vector without duplicating the data in memory?

Comment: _" Is there any way to convert a raw pointer to vector without duplicating the data in memory?"_ In short: No, there isn't, unless you use a custom allocator with the `std::vector` (check the 2nd template argument).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would you suggest any alternative way?

Comment: Just enhanced my comment a bit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm reading about it. Thank you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sure? You have an array of 30 chars, your allocator gets a request for 64 bytes. What should it do?

Comment: @n.m I don't have a good example, and tbh I never used it. Would be interesting to see a working example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think a vector can portably use an existing buffer.

Comment: @n.m. I don't think so either. But that question doesn't seem to be unsolvable. I'd go for the `std::unique_ptr` wrapping probably.

Comment: Be very careful with the concepts you're dealing with here. "... syntax above will produce a copy of the **pointer's** contents": - no. The pointer's contents is simply an address. That's what a pointer is. What the code will do is copy the **data** at the **address** that the pointer holds, i.e., it will copy the data that the pointer points to.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, of course. My words were not accurate as you said. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::vector` ¹can't use an existing buffer.

If you want to automate the lifetime management of an existing buffer you can use a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

---

<sup>*Notes:*

¹ It's technically possible to use a custom allocator to trick a `std::vector` into using an existing buffer, but exposing the data in that buffer would have to rely on non-portable aspects of the implementation.</sup>

Comment: The actually interesting thing would be to know how to write such custom allocator. Do you have some example at hand?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's easier now with C++11, I think you just have to implement `allocate` and `deallocate` (if I recall the method names correctly). The rest is inferred and defaulted via `allocator_traits`.

Comment: Smart pointer options (especially `std::unique_ptr`) would be the straight way to go it seems.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thank you. I accept it as the answer. If you suddenly had time, I'd appreciate it if you provide an example, so that others refer to it in future visits.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can't make a vector take over memory allocated by something else. But perhaps you could just use the vector to allocate it in the first place:

```
std::vector theData(LIMIT);
size_t size;
fill_with_data(theData.data(), LIMIT, &size);
theData.resize(size);
```

`data()` provides access to its internal contiguous buffer, which `fill_with_data` can then write to. The following `resize()` ensures the vector acts as if it only contains `size` amount of data.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But unfortunately the function that allocates the memory is a `C` function. It takes a `void **` and give the pointer that points to the data it has allocated. I'm talking about the `miniz library` C API for working with zip archives. Thank you, I appreciate your answer =]

Answer (score -1):

No. vector is a container, it is difference with base type data in memory. You can use type cast for base type data. You cannot point the vector elemets' memory address by yourself.

Comment: I think you can: if v is of type vector then you can point to elements like`&v[0]` and vector guarantees that elements have consecutive addresses.